# Getting invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php

I'm getting the `invalid argument supplied for foreach()` error when I try to use one of my functions.

I've looked at some other examples but couldn't find any matching cases.

My code is as follows.

**User.php:**

```
public function activateAccount($email = null, $email_code = null) {

        $field = 'email';
        $data = $this->_db->get('users', array($field, '=', $email));

        if($this->_db->count()) {
            $this->_data = $this->_db->first();
        }

        if($this->emailExists($email)) {
            if($this->data()->verified == 0) {
                $this->updateActivation('users', $email, array(
                    'verified' => 1
                ));
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;

    }

public function updateActivation($table, $fields = array(), $email = null) {

        if(!$this->_db->updateActivation($table, $email, $fields)) {
            throw new Exception('An unexpected error occurred');
        }
    }
```

**DB.php:**

```
public function updateActivation($table, $email, $fields) {
        $set = '';
        $x = 1;

        foreach($fields as $name => $value) {
            $set .= "{$name} = ?";

            if($x < count($fields)) {
                $set .= ', ';
            }
            $x++;
        }

        $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$set} WHERE email = {$email}";
        if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

If any more code is required, please let me know.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong order in the parameter list :

```
$this->updateActivation('users', $email, array('verified' => 1));
```

calls

```
updateActivation($table, $fields = array(), $email = null) {
```

I guess it should be

```
$this->updateActivation('users', array('verified' => 1), $email);
```

??

Comment: Yup that was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The

```
public function updateActivation($table, $fields = array(), $email = null) {
```

in `User.php` has the variables assigned incorrectly. Should be

```
public function updateActivation($table, $email = null, $fields = array()) {
```

or when executing the function invert the ordering to match (I think given your other function calls and assignment the former is the better approach).

```
$this->updateActivation('users', array(
                    'verified' => 1
                ), $email);
```